# how to serve image from custom folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, architecture

I have this site deployed in IIS:
[image]

Now what I am trying to do is to show an image under the App_Data folder, the path being "App_Data/uploads/abc.jpg"
In code I have this:

```
<img src="~/App_Data/uploads/abc.jpg" alt="img">
```

and then I get a 404 error suggesting resource not found. When I inspected the sources tab in chrome dev tools I have this :
[image]

This means the App_Data folder was not even served in the request in the first place now how could I serve the folder, the folder contains images of my products. Also if someone could suggest if this is a good approach since there would be thousands of product images and I don't necessarily need to serve the entire folder for each request there has to be a better way, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iis request filtering, the app_data folder cannot be accessed, so I suggest creating a new folder and uploading image to this folder.

[image]